# How to pass Int64/Int32 values through UIButton Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I want to pass a Int64/32 values from my object to a button for it to perform further operation. But `btn.tag` takes a `Int` value so it gives a error and if I change `obj.id` to `Int` then it only takes the first few numbers from the number.

```
cellBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 30, width: 100, height: 100))
        cellBtn.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
        cellBtn.setTitle("Test", forState: .Normal)

    //obj.id is Int64 value
        cellBtn.tag = obj.id

        cellBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnU), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        cell?.addSubview(cellBtn)

        return cell!

    func btnU(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("hey")
        print(sender.tag)

    }
```

How can I pass `obj.id` from the `cellBtn to btnU` so btnU has information from `obj.id`

Comment: I think it would possibly be better to subclass `UIButton` and give it a new property say `var id : Int64`.

Comment: May I ask what you're using these tags for?

Comment: I think you are missing (:) try
#selector(ClassName. btnU(_:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would not recommend passing values on UI elements, you should have model object for that purpose.
2. I would not recommend using the "tag" property since I'ts too generic. You never know witch framework will use and change the same tag value as you do.

But if you must, use a subclass, that way you can use Int64:

```
class ByButton: UIButton {
    var myValue: Int64 = 0
}
```

Or you can add run time property to all UIButtons (This is less recommended from the first solution since I'ts hard to find, and will add on all UIButtons in your application)

```
private var buttonValue: Int64 = 0
extension UIButton {
    var keyBoardHeight: CGFloat {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &buttonValue) as! CGFloat
        }
        set { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &buttonValue, newValue,  objc_AssociationPolicy(rawValue: 0)!) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

View controls aren't really meant to hold data.

You could use the button tag as an index into an array of data. (I'd add a constant value to the array index so that only non-zero tags in a certain range reference entries in your array. (Say button tags start at 100. You'd subtract 100 from the tag number and use THAT as an array index.) That's probably the cleanest way in terms of preserving the MVC design pattern. Then you could have an array of structs with whatever properties you need.

You could subclass UIButton and add an Int64 property to the subclass, as suggested by @NSGangster.

You could use associative storage to attach a new object to the button instance, but that's a bit "hack-ish".